# Auto changing the gaps,font size based on application DPI in Flexmobile

Tags: apache-flex, flexbuilder, flex-mobile

I am working on a mobile app for multi resolutions,for which the components in the screen should adjust itself based on the application DPI. How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you'd define multiple stylesheets that assign skins to your components. Each stylesheet assigns skins that render the components accordingly to the resolution/dpi used on the device.
The specific stylesheet need to be loaded and applied at runtime after determining the resolution/dpi.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `applicationDPI` property on your main `Application`.  The views will automatically adjust based on whether the device is closest to 160, 240, or 320 DPI.

See also http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WS19f279b149e7481c682e5a9412cf5976c17-8000.html